# APMO 2011 Problem 3

Tags: geometry, contest-math

> Let ABC be an acute triangle with $\angle{BAC}=30$. The internal and
>   external angle bisectors of $\angle{ABC}$ meet the line $AC$
>   at $B1$ and $B2$, respectively, and the internal and external angle
>   bisectors of $\angle{ACB}$ meet the line $AB$ at $C1$and $C2$,
>   respectively. Suppose that the circles with diameters $B1B2$
>   and $C1C2$ meet inside the triangle $ABC$ at point $P$. Prove
>   that $\angle{BPC}=90$.

I've been searching for a solution and I've encountered 2 solutions but I couldn't manage to understand it at all because it adds some point to the geometry and didn't mention anything or show the pictures. On the other hand, the solution is bit more like a writing explaining the geometry, not using geometry to explain the problem.

This problem is too difficult for me to solve and of course the drawing also give me headache ( sorry for the inconvenient without giving picture I hope someone could see it and help draw it ) so I don't know how I could say about my idea on how to solve this problem. I hope you could help me with this. Big Thanks

Comment: Please include (or summarize, or worst case provide links to) the solutions you have encountered, and say something about what you find difficult to follow. Someone may be able to help you past those difficulties. Also, this will help people avoid inadvertently duplicating those solutions. The more you can tell about what you know and/or where you're stuck, the better.

Answer (score 0):

The two circles from the problem, of diameters $B_1B_2$, and $C_1C_2$, are the circumcircles $(BB_1B_2)$, and $(CC_1C_2)$. These two circles intersect in two points. Because the problem comes with a beautiful geometrical constellation, i will give a solution clarifying the position of both intersection points, the one intersection point is $Q$, the reflexion point of $A$ w.r.t. the side $BC$, so we also know the angle $\widehat{BQC}=\widehat{BAC}=30^\circ$, the other intersection point is the point $P$ from the OP.

I will show first as a warming up (also fixing notations), considering only the circle $(BB_1B_2)$ from the OP:

> Let $\Delta ABC$ be a triangle with an angle of $30^\circ$ in $A$. Let $BB_1$ be the (inner) angle bisector of the angle $B$ in this triangle, and $BB_2$ the perpendicular on $BB_1$ (i.e. the exterior angle bisector in $B$), with $B_1,B_2\in AC$. Let $B^*$ be the mid point of $B_1B_2$. Let $x,y,z$ be angle measures (in degrees) so that $2x=\hat A=30^\circ$, $2y=\hat B$, $2z=\hat C$, so we can use only one parameter, $y$ below. Then we have:
>
> - The angle $\widehat{BB_1C}$ has the measure $30^\circ+y$.
> - $\Delta BB_1B_2$ has a right angle in $B$, so $B^*B_1=B^*B_2=B^*B$. So $\Delta B^*BB_1$ is isosceles, with angles in $B,B_1$ equal to $30^\circ+y$.
> - $\widehat{BB_1C}$ has the measure $30^\circ$, the same as the angle in $A$. So $B^*B$ is tangent in $B$ to the circumcircle $(ABC)$, (they correspond to the same arc, $\overset\frown{BC}$ in this circle), and the power of the point $B^*$ w.r.t. this circle is $B^*B^2=B^*C\cdot B^*A$.
> - The triangles $\Delta B^*BC$ and $\Delta B^*AB$ are similar, after rewriting the last relation as a proportion (and mentioning the same angle in $B^*$). And in fact this is valid for each point $R$ on the circle centered in $B^*$ and radius $B^*B=B^*B_1=B^*B_2$.
>   Let $R$ be a point on the circle $(BB_1B_2)$ (which is the Apollonius circle for the points $A,C$, corresponding to the fixed proportion $RA:RC=BA:BC$, [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circles_of_Apollonius#Apollonius'_definition_of_a_circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circles_of_Apollonius#Apollonius%27_definition_of_a_circle)). Then $RB_1$ is the angle bisector of the angle $\widehat{ARC}$.
>   [image: Apollonius circles]

Only the last point deserve some comments. Let $R$ be on the circle centered in $B^*$ with radius $B^*B=B^*B_1=B^*B_2$. Then we have the relation $B^*P^2=B^*B^2=B^*A\cdot B^*C$. There is a common angle in $B^*$ for the two triangles $\Delta B^*RC$, and $\Delta B^*AR$, so they are similar, and we can write also the third proportion now, then continue...
$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{RC}{RA}
&=
\frac{B^*C}{B^*R}
=
\frac{B^*R}{B^*A}
=
\frac{B^*B}{B^*A}
\\
&=
\frac{BC}{BA}\qquad\text{ same argument for the special position $B$ of $P$}
\\
&=\frac{B_1C}{B_1A}
\ ,
\end{aligned}
$$
so $RB_1$ is the angle bisector in $R$ in $\Delta RAC$.

$\square$

---

Now we are in position to show the location of the not needed intersection of the two circles:

> We use the above notations, also working in a triangle $\Delta ABC$ with $\hat A=2x=30^\circ$.
> Let $A'$ be the reflexion of $A$ w.r.t. the side $BC$. Then $A'B_1$ is the angle bisector of $\widehat{AA'C}$, so $A'$ is on the Appolonius circle $(BB_1B_2)$ for the points $A,C$.
> [image: The location of the point Q]

**Proof:**
Let $N$ be the foot of the perpendicular from $A$ on $BC$, and let $A'=Q$ be the symmetric point of $A$ w.r.t. $N$. Then we have with usual notations:
$$
\frac {A'A}{A'C}
=
\frac {2AN}{AC}
=
2\sin C
=\frac{\sin C}{\sin A}
=\frac ca
=
\frac{BA}{BC}
=
\frac{B_1A}{B_1C}
\ .
$$

$\square$

Since the reflection of $A$ w.r.t. side $BC$ is "the same" when exchanging in notation respectively $B, B^*, B_1, B_2$ with $C,C^*,C_1,C_2$, we see that $A'$ is also on the circle $(CC_1C_2)$, the second circle from the OP. So the second, not wanted point, is $Q=$ the reflection of $A$ in $BC$, and the corresponding angle in $Q$ in $\Delta QBC$ is $\widehat{BQC}=\widehat{BAC}=30^\circ$.

**Bonus:** We compute the angle $\widehat{AQB^*}$, and some similar other angles. Let $x_1,x_2$ be the angles in $A$ delimited by the height $AN=AQ$, so $x_1=\widehat BAN=90^\circ-2y$, and
$x_2=\widehat NAC=90^\circ-2z$. Then $QB_1$ separates $\widehat{AQC}$ in two equal angles of measure $x_2/2$. Then we have:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\widehat{AQB^*}
&=
\widehat{AQB_1}
+
\widehat{B_1QB^*}
=
\frac 12x_2+ \widehat{QB_1B^*}
=
\frac 12x_2+ \widehat{QBB_2}
\\
&=
\frac 12x_2+ \widehat{QBC}-\widehat{B_2BC}
=
\frac 12x_2+ 2y-(90^\circ-y)
\\
&=\frac 12x_2+ 3y-90^\circ\ ,
\\
\widehat{AQC^*}
&=
\frac 12x_1+ 3z-90^\circ\ ,\qquad\text{ similarly, so}
\\
\widehat{B^*QC^*}
&=
\frac 12(x_1+x_2)+ 3(y+z)-2\cdot 90^\circ
\\
&=
\frac 12\cdot 30^\circ+ 3(90^\circ-15^\circ)-2\cdot 90^\circ
=
15^\circ + 90^\circ-3\cdot 15^\circ
\\
&= 60^\circ\ .
\end{aligned}
$$

---

Let now $P$ be the other point of intersection, so it is in the opposite half-plane delimited by the line $BC$. We show $\widehat{BPC}=90^\circ$ using the knowledge of the "simpler" point $Q$:

> Claim: We have $\widehat {BPC}=90^\circ$.

**Proof:**

The angle $\widehat{B^*QC^*}$ was computed above, and
$
\widehat{B^*PC^*}
=
\widehat{B^*QC^*}
=60^\circ
$.
Then
$$
\begin{aligned}
\widehat {BPC}
&=
\widehat {C^*PC} +
\widehat {BPB^*} +
-\widehat {C^*PB^*}
\\
&=
\frac 12(180^\circ-\widehat {PC^*C})
+
\frac 12(180^\circ-\widehat {PB^*B})
-
\widehat{B^*QC^*}
\\
&=180^\circ-
\underbrace{\widehat {BQP}-\widehat {PQC}}
_{=\angle(BQC)=\angle(BAC)=30^\circ}-60^\circ
\\
&=180^\circ-30^\circ-60^\circ
\\
&=90^\circ
\end{aligned}
$$

$\square$

---

*Final comment:*
As already mentioned, the point $Q=A'$ looks simpler, its location
was shown using Apollonius circles, but maybe an other argument may be given. After having this geometric information, it is easy as above to show the location of $P$. This was for me the simplest way to present a solution.

Comment: One can compare with the more straightforward http://www.apmo-official.org/static/solutions/apmo2011_sol.pdf